# Convergence of $\left(a_{n+1}= \cfrac{{a_n}^2}{1+{a_n}} (n\ge 1) , a_1=1 \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove the sequence $\left(a_{n+1}= \cfrac{{a_n}^2}{1+{a_n}} (n\ge 1) , a_1=1\right) $ is convergent. the method I used is different from what textbook did ( It solved by mathematical induction). So I want to check whether I  did right or not. Here is my work :

Showing the sequence is decreasing ( $a_{n+1}- a_n \le 0)$ :

$a_{n+1}= \cfrac{({a_n}^2-1)+1}{1+a_n}= a_n-1 +\cfrac{1}{1+a_n}$

Hence $a_{n+1}- a_n= \cfrac{1}{1+a_n}-1= \cfrac{-a_n}{1+a_n} \le0$ (because  $a_n \ge0$)

We proved it is a decreasing sequence and we know $a_n \ge0$ therefor the sequence is bounded below and we conclude it is convergent.

Comment: The only thing you lack is to show that $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$. This (although obvious) still requires mathematical induction...

Comment: @WhatsUp Oh, good point

Comment: @Soheil: Now that you have establish convergence, notice that the limit $a$ satisfies the fixed point equation $a=\frac{a^2}{1+a}$ and so $a=0$.

Comment: @Soheil: Since everything is positive, you can slightly shorter argue that $a_{n+1} = a_n \frac{a_n}{1+a_n} < a_n$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it is a lot simpler thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This has quadratic convergence; we have $a_2 = \frac{1}{2},$ after which $a_n$  stays positive, while $$ a_{n+1} < a_n^2 $$  so that
$$ \log a_{n+1} < 2 \log a_n \; . \; $$

With  $$   \log a_2 = - \log 2 \; , \;    $$
$$   \log a_3 < -2 \log 2 \; , \;    $$

$$   \log a_4 < -4 \log 2 \; , \;    $$

$$   \log a_5 < -8 \log 2 \; , \;    $$

and

$$   \log a_{2+k} < -2^k \log 2 \; , \;    $$

$$    a_{2+k} <  \frac{1}{2^{(2^k)}}     $$