# Determining the sum of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ where $a_{n+1}=\frac{na_n^2}{1+(n+1)a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $a_0=1, a_1=\frac{1}{2}, a_{n+1}=\frac{na_n^2}{1+(n+1)a_n}$, then find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\dots$

We have $(a_n)$ is strictly decreasing as $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{-a_n(a_n+1)}{1+(n+1)a_n}<0, a_n>0$ and $ |{\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}|}<1$, then the sum is convergent.
Tried to telescope the sum by defining $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{na_n}{1+(n+1)a_n}=b_n$ (say). Eventually there was coming another sequence that was not giving any conclusion. Tried examining the behaviour of the terms of this sequence $$ a_0=1,a_1=\frac{1}{2},a_2=\frac{1}{2^3},a_3=\frac{1}{2^2(2^3+2+1)}\\a_4=\frac{3^2}{2^4(2^3+2^2)(2^3+3)(2^4(2^3+2^2)(2^3+2^2+1)+2^3+2^2+2+1)}$$
There would come up more $2^n$'s in the denominator for larger n's. Tried mimicking the solution as in the [Convergence of $\left(a_{n+1}= \cfrac{{a_n}^2}{1+{a_n}} (n\ge 1) , a_1=1 \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839242/convergence-of-lefta-n1-cfraca-n21a-n-n-ge-1-a-1-1-right) (seems a bit relatable), but  I am stuck here.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $0 < a_{n+1} < a_n$ then it doesn't follow that the sum is convergent. E.g. $a_n = \frac{1}n$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. yes, you are correct, but I made this comment not by $a_{n+1}-a_n<0$, but on the basis of the behaviour of initial terms only (agree on it being incomplete, but it was an attempt to use the ratio test for converging sum).

Comment: As $0 < a_{n+1} < a_n \le \frac12$ then $\exists lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$. We may find that the first elements are $0.5, 0.125, 0.022727272727272728,$ $0.0014204545454545455, 8.013847929221696e-06, 3.2109335400359393e-10$, $6.186056505212527e-19, 2.6787106559977557e-36,$
$5.740392622844741e-71$ (in Python notation) so it looks like $a_n \to 0$ very fast and even $n a_n \to 0$, $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Put $b_n = n a_n$ and show that $0 < b_{n+1} < b_n$. Hence $\exists \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = b \ge 0$. Then in recurrent formula for $b_n$ we may take $n \to \infty$ and get $b=0$. Hence $b_n \to 0$ and thus $a_n \to 0$.  Maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @BotnakovN. I will try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the sequence $b_n=na_n$ and notice that $b_{n}-b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n}{1+\frac{n+1}{n}b_n}\in(0,b_n)$ for $n>0$, so $b_n$ is positive and decreasing, and thereby convergent. Let $b=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n$. Combining the convergence with the above we have $0=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(b_{n+1}-b_n)=\frac{b}{1+b}$, which gives $b=0$.

On the other hand, notice that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{b_n^2}{na_n(1+(n+1)a_n)}=b_{n}-b_{n+1}$ and hence $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n(b_{k}-b_{k+1})=b_1+b_1-b_{n+1}=1-b_{n+1}$. Since we have already established that $b=0$, we have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$.

Answer (score 4):

You can rearrange your equation in the following manner

$a_{n+1} (1 +  (n+1) a_n) = n a_n^2$

$ na_n^2-(n+1)a_{n+1}a_n = a_{n+1}$

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = na_n-(n+1)a_{n+1}$

The terms on the right hand side cancel out once you apply summation on both sides leaving

$\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = a_1$.

Note: Let the limit of $a_n$ as n approaches $\infty$ be $L_\infty$. You get two values for the limit: 0 and -1 by using the second equation above.

$L_\infty^2 n -(n+1)L_\infty^2= L_\infty$

$-L_\infty^2 = L_\infty$

Since all the terms are positive as you have shown $L_\infty = 0$.

Edit (Thanks to @Matija for pointing this out):
The convergence of the series $na_n$ needs to be shown instead of the series $a_n$.

Comment: I like your argument! But you have to show that $na_n$ converges to $0$. I think, first you should show that it does converge (it's decreasing), and then, that the limit of $na_n$ (not $a_n$) is $0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. @Matija