# Is there anti-derivative of sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider this problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h491143p2754507

> Define the sequence $a_0,a_1,\dots$ inductively by $a_0=1,\,
> a_1=\frac12,\,$ and
> $$ a_{n+1} = \frac{na_n^2}{1+(n+1)a_n},\;\;\forall n\ge 1. $$
> Show that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$
> converges and determine its value.

How could they come up with $na_n - (n+1)a_{n+1} = \dfrac{n a_n}{1+(n+1)a_n} $. I have encountered many problems on series of numbers to find the limit of a series of sums, and have a solution using the difference as above. How could I think like that. Is there a general method or literature that can solve such problems? Any help from you is greatly appreciated

Comment: By grabbing a pen and paper and trying different approaches until you find the right one. There is no "secret" to getting better at mathematics. 

Furthermore, a perfect solution is really written backwards. That is, the person who did this the very first time (I assure you they did a lot of scratch work) found eventually that the term $\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ can be written in that specific form which allows telescoping. Then they ditch the scratchwork and write a clean solution from the beginning and that's why the mysterious part usually appears in the beginning.

Comment: It's like writing an essay. You spend lots of time drafting and figuring out your arguments  and eventually you do find them. Now is the time to write your polished essay and what do you do? Do you include all the scratch work, most of which are useless, that led to your final arguments? Or do you immediately introduce your main points/findings in the first paragraph and topic sentence ?

Comment: Now for the actual piece of advice on math problems - this is an exercise on creating telescoping series. You said you have seen many similar problems, so this means you should have some rough idea to begin with for this problem. You are given one equation and so all you have to do and all you can do is to keep manipulating them in different ways, until you find something that is useful. 

For this problem, it's staring at you right there - you want to simplify things like $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and the given relation gives that by just dividing both sides by $a_n.$

Comment: The problem is already solved here, you can have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621173/determining-the-sum-of-fraca-n1a-n-where-a-n1-fracna-n21n1?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The question is about

> Define the sequence $a_0,a_1,\dots$ inductively by $a_0=1,\,
> a_1=\frac12,\,$ and
> $$ a_{n+1} = \frac{na_n^2}{1+(n+1)a_n},\;\;\forall n\ge 1. $$
> Show that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$
> converges and determine its value.
> Is there a general method or literature that can solve such problems?

The question is

> Is there a general method or literature that can solve such problems?

You are essentially asking for a general method to sum any
finite or infinite series. No such method can exist. However,
there is the [Wilf-Zeilberger method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair)
(but unfortunately doesn't apply to this specific problem).

What you can do is perform some computations and observe the
results. First, a slight redefinition of the sequence will
be useful. Thus define a new sequence by

$$ A_0\ne 0,\quad A_n = \frac{n A_{n-1}^2}{1+(n+1)A_{n-1}},
\;\;\forall n>0. \tag1 $$

The relation to the old sequence is
$\,\frac12 = A_0,\, a_{n+1} = A_n.\,$

Compute the first few values of the sequence to get

$$ A_1 = \frac{A_0^2}{1 + 2A_0}, \\
 A_2 = \frac{2A_0^4}{(1 + 2A_0)(1 + 2A_0 + 3A_0^2)}, \\
 A_3 = \frac{12A_0^8}{(1 + 2A_0)(1 + 2A_0 + 3A_0^2)
(1 + 4A_0 + 7A_0^2 + 6A_0^3 + 8A_0^4)}. \tag2 $$

An immediate observation is the numerator. The recursion
equation implies that the numerator of $\,A_n\,$ is equal
to $\,s_n A_0^{2^n}\,$ where $\,s_n\,$ is the
[OEIS sequence A052129](https://oeis.org/A052129)
defined by $\,s_0=1,\, s_n=n\,s_{n-1}^2.\,$

Define the first quotient sequence $\, B_n := A_{n+1}/A_n.\,$
Compute the first few values to get

$$ B_0 = \frac{A_0}{1 + 2A_0}, \\
B_1 = \frac{2A_0^2}{1 + 2A_0 + 3A_0^2}, \\
B_2 = \frac{6A_0^4}{1 + 4A_0 + 7A_0^2 + 6A_0^3 + 8A_0^4}.
\tag3 $$

The numerator of $\,B_n\,$ is $\,(n+1)s_nA_0^{2^n}.\,$ Its denominator
is related to the denominator of $\,A_n.\,$
Define its partial sum sequence as $\,C_n := \sum_{k=0}^n B_k.\,$
Compute the first few values to get

$$ C_0 = \frac{A_0}{1 + 2A_0}, \\
C_1 = \frac{A_0(1 + 4A_0 + 7A_0^2}{(1 + 2A_0)(1 + 2A_0 + 3A_0^2)}, \\
C_2 = \frac{A_0(1 + 8A_0 + 30A_0^2 + 68A_0^3 + 105A_0^4 + 116A_0^5
+ 92A_0^6)}{(1 + 2A_0)(1 + 2A_0 + 3A_0^2)(1 + 4A_0 + 7A_0^2 + 6A_0^3 + 8A_0^4)}. \tag4 $$

It is time to examine the denominators of $\,A_n.\,$ The sequence is

$$ D_0 = 1, \\
 D_1 = 1 + 2A_0, \\
 D_2 = 1 + 4A_0 + 7A_0^2 + 6A_0^3, \\
 D_3 = 1 + 8A_0 + 30A_0^2 + 68A_0^3 + 105A_0^4 + 116A_0^5
+ 92A_0^6 + 48A_0^7. \tag5 $$

Comparing the sequence $\,C_{n-1}\,$ with $\,A_n\,$ and using
$\,D_n\,$ we observe that

$$ \frac{A_0}{A_n} = \frac{C_{n-1}}{A_n} + (n+1). \tag6 $$

For example, for $\,n=2,\,$

$$ \frac{A_0}{A_2} = \frac{1 + 4A_0 + 7A_0^2 + 6A_0^3}{2A_0^3} = \\
\frac{C_1}{A_2} + (2+1) = \frac{1 + 4A_0 + 7A_0^2}{2A_0^3} + 3.
\tag7 $$

Equation $(6)$ rewritten is

$$ C_{n-1} = A_0 - (n+1)A_n. \tag8 $$

Now, assuming $\,0 < A_0 < 1,\,$ then $\,A_n\to\infty\,$ as
$n\to\infty.\,$ Take limits in equation $(8)$ to get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A_{k+1}}{A_k} = A_0. \tag9 $$

Answer (score 1):

There is a book by Andreescu and Gelca called putnam and beyond, the 3rd chapter on sequences and series has plenty of stuff your question (which I am sure is an old undergrad olympiad problem, maybe IMC? ) .

I cannot reproduce a chapter in just an answer but mainly the main points are:

1. Plug in some values to guess a general pattern
2. Play arround with the recurrence untill you get something that strikes as useful, the correct statement is:

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = na_{n} - (n+1)a_{n+1}$

not the one you have in your post, but the thing is that after playing arround with the reccurence a bit and you end up with the above you should be able to recognise that this telescopises. Hope that helps.